# connecting to spark data frames in tableau

Tags: apache-spark, hive, tableau-api, apache-spark-sql

We are trying to generate reports in tableau by spark SQL connectivity, But i found out that we are ultimately connecting to hive meta-store.

If this is the case what are the advantages of this new spark SQL connection. Is there a way to connect to spark data frames that are persisted, from tableau using spark SQL.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is a Tableau problem more than a Spark problem. Spark SQL Connector launches a Spark job each time you connect to a database. Part of that Spark job loads the underlying Hive table into the distributed memory that Spark manages, and each time you make a change or select on a graph, the refresh has to go a level deeper to Hive metastore to get the data, through Spark. That is how Tableau is designed. The only option here is to change Tableau for Spotfire (or some other tool) where by pre-caching the underlying Hive table, the Spark SQL Connector can query it directly from Spark distributed memory, skipping the load step.
Disclosure: I am in no way associated with Spotfire makers